# How do I select/move multiple albums or events in the Photos sidebar?

Tags: macos, photos, sidebar

I like the new sidebar in Yosemite Photos. But after upgrading to Photos from iPhoto on my iMac, I have literally dozens of "Events" that need to be moved into "Albums."

With other sidebar windows (like Finder), I can hold down "command" or "shift" and select multiple folders at once; that does not seem to work in Photos. I do not want to move each event separately. Every time I try to drag or select more than one event/album, it defaults to one selection.

How can I select more than one event/album at once?
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise album view as prior suggested and then drag albums into the sidebar to achieve the desired result, but you are absolutely correct in noting the failure of this desired behaviour to operate, purely within the sidebar itself.
yup the OSX HCI / UX toolbox in terms of standardisation of elements with predictable results is something that apple has debased since leaving OS9, selectable text OS wide - has similar issues.

Comment: Lifesaver - just saved me many æons of work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Albums view instead. By clicking the "Albums" button at the top of the window, you will be presented with a full-page view of your albums. By selecting "iPhoto Events," you will have access to all your iPhoto events, and will be able to Cmd/Shift-select them.

Finally, by displaying the sidebar, you will be able to drag multiple selected Events into a given Album.

Comment: Hi--sorry I took so long to reply; just finally had a chance to try it. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Cannot select more than one item in the sidebar, no matter what view or combination of keys I use.

I cannot believe Apple would do this, especially since I can do it in other applications...come to think of it, I can't select multiple items in the Finder sidebar either. WTH?
There has to be a way. Cannot imagine they expect people to manually move dozens of items one at a time.

But thank you for answering, aaplmath!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. However, I was not suggesting you would be able to select multiple items in the sidebar. Instead, I was trying to present an alternate way that will select you multiple items. I believe you are correct–multiple items in the sidebar can not be selected at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I just found your question when I ran into the same problem.
It is possible: from the 'Photos' or 'All Photos' view, select all the photos/events you want to, and then instead of using the '+' at the right-hand side of an event title, use the '+' which is in the app title bar, next to the 'Share' and 'Search' box.